# suppress warning in code

Tags: delphi, warnings

in eclipse java there are operators that help suppress warning in code.

is such suppression in delphi?

and

warning off

warning on

is two commands.

Comment: Yes, these are called "compiler directives". One example is `{$WARN NO_RETVAL OFF}` / `{$WARN NO_RETVAL ON}`.

Comment: @Andreas, why is your answer posted as a comment... I think your answer is ok and shall be posted as an answer. :)

Comment: @jachguate: I didn't feel it was complete enough for an answer... Besides, I suspect this is a duplicate question.

Comment: No there isn't, and anyone who says otherwise gets shot!!! -- Seriously though, Hints & Warnings tell you there's a problem. Don't _hide_ the problem **fix** it!

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't found it, these can very easily be controlled from the Project Options dialog:

[image]

Comment: yes, this does not help supress a warning for an individual line of code.

Comment: @none You didn't state in your question that you wanted it for an individual line of code.

Comment: (@David: I don't know Java, but the talk about "operators" indicates that the OP wishes to do this in code at least.)